# push to gateway function in prometheus client

Tags: python, nginx, prometheus

I want to push metrics to my Prometheus server via the push_to_gateway function but I set basic auth on the Prometheus server.
how can I send a username and password in the push_to_gateway function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official case, you can try to use it to test

this model
`https://pypi.org/project/prometheus-client/`

`pip install prometheus-client`

```py
from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, Gauge, push_to_gateway
from prometheus_client.exposition import basic_auth_handler

def my_auth_handler(url, method, timeout, headers, data):
    username = 'foobar'
    password = 'secret123'
    return basic_auth_handler(url, method, timeout, headers, data, username, password)
registry = CollectorRegistry()
g = Gauge('job_last_success_unixtime', 'Last time a batch job successfully finished', registry=registry)
g.set_to_current_time()
push_to_gateway('localhost:9091', job='batchA', registry=registry, handler=my_auth_handler)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the code snippet comes from the README of the prometheus-client source repository, i.e. https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/v0.16.0/README.md#handlers-for-authentication